# How to read jBoss configuration files in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I want to have a project independent configuration file that I can access from different projects. What I'm currently trying (and does not give me good results at all):

```
<bean id="wroProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">  
<property name="location" value="${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/wro.properties" />  
</bean>
```

I use `Spring 3` and `JBoss 7.1`. My configuration files are under `jboss/standalone/configuration/....properties`. Besides that I want to read message files from that same directory with:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="messages,local" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Currently it looks for `messages.properties` and `local.properties` in `src` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up using, which is platform independent and portable:

```
<bean id="wroProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="file:#{systemProperties['jboss.home.dir']}/standalone/configuration/wro.properties" />  
</bean>
```

The configuration of the message source is identical.

Answer (score 0):

A `ResourceBundleMessageSource` uses the `basenames` provided to (and the locale) to build a resource name (ex. `message.properties`) which is eventually (in the call stack) used by [`java.util.ResourceBundle.Control#newBundle(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html#newBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20boolean%29). This resource name is then looked for on the classpath starting at its root (ex. `/message.properties`).

If you're on an IDE like Eclipse, your classpath very likely starts at `src`.

If `jboss/standalone/configuration/...` is on your classpath as well and the properties file are in there, you can change the `basenames` to

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="jboss/standalone/configuration/messages,jboss/standalone/configuration/local" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Would that be portable to other team members and automatical builds that do not have this `classpath` configuration? Also, what about the property value?

Comment: `classpath` is not an optional configuration. The Java application launcher requires it even if you are not aware of it. What do you mean by _what about the property value_?

Comment: I asked whether your answer is also applicable to configure `<property name="location" value="/standalone/configuration/wro.properties" />`?

Comment: @Milan Yes, if that path is on the root of the classpath, it will work as intended. To understand the classpath, perhaps read this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)).